# Why is array_pop() returning the last item of the array instead of deleting it?

Tags: php

`array_pop()` is returning the last item of the array instead of deleting the last item of the array. Why is this happening?

```
$blam = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$blam = explode("/", $blam); 
$blam = array_pop($blam);
print_r($blam);
```

[You can test out the php here.](http://phpfiddle.org/)

Comment: You're overriding the variable with the last item...

Comment: `array_pop()` returns the element popped from the array; and modifies the array by reference.... as described in the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: Maybe it seems obvious at this point, but just to explicitly state it, if you want to only remove the last item, use `array_pop($blam);` instead of `$blam = array_pop($blam);`.

Comment: down-voting fairies at it again, totally legit question that may help others as it helped me... this is not such an obvious mistake

Comment: This is a grate question, in all the answers given. I found a lot of excellent knowledge.
Why was it down boated so lightly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Problem**

You are doing the pop operation correctly, but immediately you are assigning the currently removed element to the variable $blam. So it iffectively makes that variable hold the value i.e the element that was popped.

**Solution**

Don't assign the value returned by pop function to the variable.

**Code**

```
$blam = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$blam = explode("/", $blam); 
array_pop($blam);
print_r($blam);
```

Answer (score 6):

You're **overriding** the variable. If you need the removed value, change it to

```
$foo = array_pop($blam);
```

---

The function is behaving as expected. From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php):

> array_pop() pops and returns the last value of the array, shortening the array by one element.

When you use

```
$blam = array_pop($blam);
```

*You're saying:*
"Remove the last element from `$blam` and store it inside `$blam`",  replacing the previous content with said element.

To elaborate, I think the confusion here is that **array_pop does NOT return the new array**, it instead **returns the removed value**, *changing* the original array.